IIS (on Win2019) Missing "Authorization Rules"
On Windows 2019, I have a web app with "Windows Auth" enabled, but I don't see the link "Authorization Rules" to add users, and groups (as I have on an older server).
This is what I see on my old server, that's not on the new server:

This is my "Roles and Features" settings on the new server:

I have Windows Auth enabled on the new server (I just turned of Anonymous after taking the screen shot):


It looks like you also need to select 'URL Authorization' in the "Roles and Features" for "Web Server"

